# Updating UI from callback function

Tags: objective-c

I'm performing asynchronous request with [ASI HTTP Request](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) and I want to update Textbox with new information from the request, so I'm updating it from callback function. 
Here is my code so far:

**Second Class**

```
- (void)Login {
    NSLog(@"Login");
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ts5.travian.sk/login.php"];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(loginRequestFinished:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(loginRequestFailed:)];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)loginRequestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSLog(@"Completed!");
    NSString *response = [request responseString];
    AppController *ac = [AppController getInstance];
    [ac.textbox performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setStringValue:) withObject:response waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

AppController is a main class. Setting text from there is working. But this code isnt doing anything. It just wrote 2 log lines to debug window.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you confirm that `ac` is not `nil`? Can you post the code of the method `getInstance` of `AppController`? Can you also confirm that `ac.textbox` is not `nil`?

Comment: What does [AppController getInstance] do? Are you certain it's returning the correct references?

Comment: getInstance ensures that this class is singleton. ac isn't nil, but textbox is nil. Dont know why because textbox is a property: @property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *textbox;

Comment: If you never load the AppController.xib, I think your textBox would be nil. The xib should load for your textBox to have a valid address.